# How to get date like this Sept 15th 2011 in oracle query result instead of 15sep2011_00:00:00?

Tags: java, oracle

I am executing a query

```
select level as VERSION,
name as DESCRIPTION,code as CODE,created as RELEASEDATE
,SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, '.',-1)+1) as TYPE
from mytable
where code = 'HX56UO'
```

which gives result like

```
Type    Version     Description       Release Date   
.exe    3.0.2   MPC560xB MCAL Autosar 3.x    15sep2011_00:00:00
```

I need release date like this Sept 15th 2011 and i need to set this result value in a bean set method.

```
public void setLastDate(java.util.Calendar newLastPubDate) {

    lastDate = newLastDate;

}
```

what type casting i need to do in setting the above value from result set
since the set method is of calender.
i tried like setting the value like this

```
if (rs.getDate("RELEASEDATE") != null ) {
Bean.setLastPubDate(rs.getdate"RELEASEDATE"));
}
```

But it is not date format,its of calender how to set the value.
Please help me solving this.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the DB type of `created` (releasedate) column ? in oracle sql you can convert a `date` datatype to a string in the format you ask for by using `to_date` function with `mon ddth yyyy` format ie: `select to_char(sysdate, 'mon ddth yyyy') from dual`

Comment: @A.B.Cade:thanks its of VARCHAR2 type,how can i convert this.Please help me

Comment: Then use `to_date` function (like in this example: `select to_date('15sep2011_00:00:00', 'ddmonyyyy_hh24:mi:ss') from dual`)  in the sql and then one af the 2 suggestions you've already got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `created` column is a `VARCHAR2` - very bad practice to not store a date as a `DATE` but we'll skip that for now - you need to convert it to a date type somewhere, and in the query is possibly simplest:

```
select level as VERSION,
    name as DESCRIPTION,
    code as CODE,
    TO_DATE(created,'DDMONYYYY_HH24:MI:SS') as RELEASEDATE,
    SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, '.',-1)+1) as TYPE
from mytable
where code = 'HX56UO'
```

You can still use `getDate()` from the resultset, and need to convert that Date to a Calendar object as you call your bean method:

```
Bean.setLastPubDate(Calendar.getInstance().setTime(rs.getDate("RELEASEDATE"));
```

Comment: Thanks alex but i need to convert that format in result like this sep 15th 2011 then i need to set that format(what ever the format its converted) in to set method of calender type.Please help me how to solve it.

Comment: If the `mytable.created` column in the database is of type `DATE`, then you don't need to convert it. When you query it through SQL*Plus or whatever, your NLS settings determine how it is converted to a string for display. This relates to what A.B.Cade was referring to. It is a `DATE` in Oracle, and still a date object in the resultset, and can be passed to Calendar. How you format the display of a Calendar date is a different question.

Comment: but the column is of varchar :(.. how to convert like according to my requirement.

Comment: @anto - updated to convert your `varchar` to a date in the query

Comment: yes its working thanks.. but i have converted the date format to char. Now how to set that char value to method of calender type.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (rs.getDate("RELEASEDATE") != null ) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(rs.getDate("RELEASEDATE"));
    Bean.setLastPubDate(calendar);
}
```

EDIT:
When you later want to convert the calendar to a string (to display it), you can use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(bean.getLastPubDate().getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks.. but first i need to convert that type to format like sep 15th 2011 the i need to set that format in calender bean.Please help me how to solve it.

Comment: That makes no sense. A calendar has no "format", it's a point in time. You format the date/calendar when you want to *convert* it to a string. See my edit above.

Comment: Never mind. I saw in one of your comments that the field was a VARCHAR. Changes things a bit, but you already got an answer for that.